# Deciding the shuffle partition size and number of partitions in spark

Tags: performance, apache-spark, optimization, pyspark, databricks

Can any of you tell how the below formula works in terms of shuttle partition file size and number of shuffle partitions ?

100 cores

150 shuffle partitions

750 MB avg shuffle file size --------how is it calculated ?

---

Either Decrease the shuffle partition to 100

1.125 gb avg shuffle partition size

1 cycle of tasks          --------how is it calculated ?

---

Or Increase the shuffle paritions to 200

562.5 MB avg shuffle partition size       --------how is it calculated ?

2 cycles of tasks

Comment: Since, `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions` is the degree of parallelism, decreasing its value will mean dividing your job over fewer tasks which throws larger amount of data at each task on an average. And conversely.

Comment: I am clear on that. But Is there any relationship between shuffle partiton size and (number of cores, shuffle partitons). I mean a way to calculate it

Comment: Total file size / Shuffle Partitions = Partition Size. The number of cores denotes the number of parallel tasks that can run simultaneously. Since a task is created for each partition, the cycle of tasks is     Shuffle Partitions / Number of cores.